# White vertical gap when printing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

A customer reported an issue with a report. A vertical white gap line appears between columns of a table when it is printed. It is highly unlikely that this is an issue with the printer, because I was able to reproduce the issue with our printer and the gap lines appeared at the exact same spot as at our customer.

The report has a body width of 27.2cm and consists of a single table with ten columns. There are no margins and no borders. The reports renders perfectly in report designer no matter what I do to the column sizes, however, the gaps appear at different locations if I change the individual column sizes. There is also a header row where the last nine columns are merged together in three cells.

[image: Report rendered in report viewer]

With one column width 4.7cm and nine columns with 2.5cm (4.7 + 9 * 2.5 = 27.2) It is printed like this:
[image]

With one column width 4.52cm and nine columns with 2.52cm (4.52 + 9 * 2.52 = 27.2) It is printed like this:

[image]

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the direction of why the cell size would cause this rendering flaw, and what I can do to resolve it.

Comment: I've seen similar behaviour in PDF exports. You say you don't have any borders set, which of course is reasonable, but in some cases I remember solving it by actually adding borders of the same colour; for some reason this managed to colour in the whitespace. It's a case of trial and error - sometimes having the border set on one side and not the other worked, sometimes borders made things worse. But I'd play around with explicitly setting your borders to see if it makes a difference. It's only a guess so I'll keep this as a comment, but it might help.

Comment: @IanPreston ok, trial and error has been my approach thus far. Thanks for the tip regarding the borders - I'll try that.